# angular 8 call android @JavascriptInterface method

Tags: android, angular

I got a angular app deployed to apache server. Android app only create a webview and add JavascriptSupport like below

```
webView=this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptSupport(this), "jsinterface");
```

Android app has a toast method like below:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void toast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I tried to call toast method from angular 8 app but no luck. Angular code like this

```
export interface JavascriptInterface {
    toast(message: string): void;
}
```

In another class I call this interface method

```
public jsinterface: JavascriptInterface;

showtoast() {
    this.jsinterface.toast("Hello");
}
```

But I got error in emulator console like this

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source: http://<angular app url>/main-es2015.3bb15247496d83d1869d.js (1)
```

How can I call android method properly.

Thanks,

Comment: did you find a solution for this. I get a compilation error while trying to access the interface since it;s not declared

Comment: Sorry, still no solution for this. I give up and write native android app

Comment: I found one solution, I tested it on my application it works. Declare your interface like this "declare var jsInterface: JavascriptInterface;"